# Math symbols not being printed.

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols, unicode-math, mathspec

I am having problems printing an equation. I have the following definitions:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,BoldFeatures={Weight=2}}

\setmathfont[
    Scale=0.95,
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont= *-regular,
    BoldFont=*-bold,
    ItalicFont=*-italic,
    BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
]{texgyrethermes}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation} 
        \label{constraint:inference} 
        D \models C \iff V(D) \models \top \Longrightarrow V(C) \models \top 
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This is the putput that I am getting:

[image]

Comment: it's helpful for this kind of question to post a complete minimal example (with `\begin{document}...\end{document}`) instead of the separate code pieces.

Comment: Added a complete example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `\usepackage{unicode-math}` command.  This package is only for use with specific unicode math fonts (of which there are only about three: Cambria Math, Asana Math and xits).  So you should stick with `mathspec`.

Comment: Like a charm. I wasn't aware that that package could be the problem.

Comment: @Tiago Yes, unless you are using one of those three fonts, you shouldn't use the package at all.

Comment: In fact, `unicode-math` doesn't really behave well because it hijacks the math font selection even if its `\setmathfont` command isn't executed at all.

Comment: @Alan, in fact their are also Neo Euler and Stix fonts

Comment: @Matsaya Thanks for the info. Is Neo Euler completely ready for use?

Comment: @Alan, Neo Euler isn't completely finished, but I think you can use it if you are vigilant. See https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf